# Python 3: how to parse a csv file where the text fields can contain embedded new line characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

When exporting excel/libreoffice sheets where the cells can contain new lines as CSV, the resulting file will have those new lines preserved as literal newline characters not something like the char string "\n".

The standard csv module in Python 3 apparently does not handle this as would be necessary. The documentation says "Note The reader is hard-coded to recognise either '\r' or '\n' as end-of-line, and ignores lineterminator. This behavior may change in the future." . Well, duh.

Is there some other way to read in such csv files properly? What csv really should do is ignore any new lines withing quoted text fields and only recognise new line characters outside a field, but since it does not, is there a different way to solve this short of implementing my own CSV parser?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with something like `df = pandas.read_csv('my_data.csv')`. You'll have more granular control over how the data is read in. If you're worried about formatting, you can also [set](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/33788/change-column-separator-on-csv-export/) the delimiter for the csv from libreoffice to something that doesn't occur in nature like `;;`